# C - dir path last folder - gibberish at the end

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, directory

I want to get the last folder in a directory path.

for example I have this directory path :

```
/home/workspace/projects/files/example.c
```

and I want to get "files"

I am using

```
basename((dirname("/home/workspace/projects/files/example.c")));
```

I want to export "files" to .csv file and I get gibberish at the end , something like "files�"

**Update:**
I also tried this :

```
  char * path = strdup(file);
  basename(dirname(path));
```

char * file points on "/home/workspace/projects/files/example.c"
and its not working too  ,"files" still written to .csv with junk in the end,but when I print basename(dirname(file)) to console it prints well "files"

Comment: From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/basename): "*Both dirname() and basename() may modify the contents of path*" - but modifying a string literal invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: it should be /home I think so.

Comment: Your compiler should give you a warning for passing a `const char*` to a function taking a `char*`.

Comment: @achal - yea I meant /home - I'm editing it ,sorry

Comment: @Kevin - Alas in C, a string literal is not `const char *` :/  https://ideone.com/GrsGsc

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Ah, right... Perhaps I was thinking of older versions of C++ that gave a warning (not an error) for it.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth In C, The behavior of modifying string literal is implementation behavior, due to ancient grudges.

Comment: @Stargateur - C99 (at least) claims it's UB - see the answer below.  Maybe that was not the case in earlier standards revisions?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth They was modifiable in ANSI(never be a true standard) and this has been change in C89. Of course in C11, it's still undefined behavior but in fact C didn't change the type of literal string to const because they allow implementation to do as they like, but they tell it's undefined behavior to allow optimization (store same literal in the same place). De facto, it's more implemented behavior than undefined behavior because of the type. It's a contraction between C semantic and C standard. Personally, I still wait that the type change to `char const *`... maybe in C3011...

Comment: Your update is not sufficient.  "it's not working" tell us nothing useful.  **How** is it not working?  Your post should have a [mcve] that others can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Even C90 said (§6.1.4 String literals): _If the program attempts to modify
a string literal of either form, the behavior is undefined._  The words in C99 are (§6.4.5 String literals): _If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
undefined._ and [C11](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p7) is identical to C99 in this (same section number; same words).  It has always been UB to modify a string literal in standard C.

Answer (score 3):

As was mentioned in the comments, both `dirname` and `basename` can modify the argument passed to it.  What you're passing however is a string literal, which cannot be modified.  Attempting to do so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this particular case results to extra characters being printed.

Section 6.4.5 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding string literals says the following:

> *7* It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.

You need to store this string in either an array or a dynamically allocated buffer.  Then you can modify it.

```
char path[] = "/home/workspace/projects/files/example.c";
basename((dirname(path)));
```

Here, `path` is declared as an array, and this array is *initialized* with a string literal.  It is not a string literal itself.

Comment: I did this with char * path ="/home/workspace/projects/files/example.c" , and still same problem. do you know why ?

Comment: @AvivEyal You still have a pointer to a string literal, not an array.  Use the syntax given in the answer.

Comment: I cant use it this way you recommended , I must use a pointer. I tried to copy the pointer with strcpy(path,file)  - when char* file="home...\..\example.c" . but its not working neither

Comment: Then make a copy using `strdup`: `char *path = strdup("/home...");`  Be sure to `free` it afterword.

Comment: can it be char * path = strdup(file) ? ( char * file points on "/home...") and then basename(dirname(path))  ?

Comment: not working too - I guess I will split the string with other functions

Comment: @AvivEyal It should work.  If it's not, update your question with what you have.